# Prestashop 1.6.1.6 updating values from database

Tags: mysql, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to update product price values, directly from database. I tried with the first 3 lines values, and everything goes fine at database level. The problem is that new values do not refresh at the web application. 
I already clear cache, and re-built the product's index. But nothing happens.
Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u want to change price directly in database you have to change it in product table and also in product_shop table.

Comment: Perfect. Also if I only update product_shop table, the site is updating. Thank you.